# Prove that, the ratio of two consecutive terms of an arithmetic series converges at 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

How would one prove that in an arithmetic series, as $n$ approaches infinity, the ratio of the $n^{th}$ and the $(n-1)^{th}$ term approaches $1$?

[That basically means the bigger the terms of an arithmetic series get, the closer the ratio of two consecutive terms gets to 1].

Comment: Hint. Write down the algebra that tells you what those two terms are and look at their ratio. If you try that and you're still stuck, [edit] the question to show us your work and we will try to help.

Comment: arithmetic sequence means that the difference $a_n-a_{n-1}=d$ is constant. Thus the ratio $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \frac{a_{n-1}+d}{a_{n-1}}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$